Delete the first line match for a domain in a list of domains
So if I have a list of domains in a text file:

fake.domain/file

google.com/drive/folders

stackoverflow/questions

google.com/drive/files


I'd want to be able to submit a string "google.com/drive" and only have it remove the first one it sees, without wiping out anything above it. In other words, I'm looking for a sed or other bash expression that would allow me to match a string and delete ONLY the line of the first instance that string is found on.
So submitting google.com/drive would leave me with this:

fake.domain/file

stackoverflow/questions

google.com/drive/files


I have this but it keeps wiping out everything up to the match:
sed -i '0,\|$string|d" $domain_list
I've been having trouble since most solutions use forward slashes, which I do not seem able to use because the strings I am submitting have them as well. I really appreciate any help on this.

I think you were close, try sed -i "0,\|$string|{//d}" file.

This might help too.

@oguzismail That worked, thank you!

Your question should remain strictly a question. Please don't add "SOLVED" or answers into the question.
